# AS3 -TypeError #1009 - any easy way to find out *which* object reference is null?

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling, object, null

We all get "TypeError #1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference" now and then - no big deal, but sometimes frustrating to debug.

Flash gives you the call stack (which is a start), but leaves it up to you to figure out where the null object is - is it possible to find out *exactly which* reference is throwing the error?

Given the following (error prone) function:

```
function nullObjectReferenceError():void
    {
        var obj:Object;
        var prop:* = obj.nonExistentProperty;
    }
```

Rather than just the call stack from the TypeError, I'd like to trace something like: "*Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at **obj.nonExistentProperty***" - Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check Permit Debugging under Publish Settings in the Flash IDE, it gives you the line number in your code causing the error.

Comment: Ah - getting closer... still can't get the Object, but the line number makes it much easier to find. Do you know if "Permit Debugging" has any consequences for security or performance ?

Comment: I'm marking this one as correct - it seems to be the closest thing to a solution that's available.

Comment: It should only be used while you're testing/debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to stop using such generic error-prone code in the first place. You should never use '*' type, and almost never should use 'Object' type.

To catch it at runtime, you could always say:

```
if(obj == null)
  throw new Error("null obj passed in!!");

if(obj.nonExistentProperty == null)
  throw new Error("obj doesn't have the prop!! the obj was: "+obj);
```

Comment: actually davr, I was asking because I am often called upon to debug code written by other developers... but this is generally good advice.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError` will not give you any more information if you catch it.

As far as I know, there is no known way to achieve this (i.e *which* object threw the Error).

Your best bet will be to set a breakpoint in the beginning of the function and investigate the variables manually. That's what I do, and that works fairly well for me.

Comment: I thought as much - I use TextMate as my code editor so setting breakpoints is a bit fiddly - I was hoping for some other solution