# TypeError #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference - flash cc game building

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I'm currently creating my first game using actionscript 3 and I'm extremely amateur to say the least! I can't figure out how to fix the error #1009 that keeps popping up. I've tried identifying the variable and a few other things my uni lecturer suggested but I still can't get it to work. I traced it and found that it was

```
ageDisplay.text = int(myAge).toString();
```

that is the problem. It's in the following code:

```
function updateAge (myAge:Number){

    //show age with no decimals places, and as a string
    var ageDisplay:TextField;
    ageDisplay.text = int(myAge).toString();
    /////trace ("my current age is:" + myAge);

}
```

Any suggestions on what i've done wrong here? I'm desperate and it's really bugging me i can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 -TypeError #1009 - any easy way to find out \*which\* object reference is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518118/as3-typeerror-1009-any-easy-way-to-find-out-which-object-reference-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ageDisplay:TextField;
ageDisplay.text = int(myAge).toString();
```

This is your problem. `ageDisplay` is `null` because you never assign anything to it. For example:

```
var ageDisplay:TextField = new TextField();
ageDisplay.text = int(myAge).toString();
```

Of course, that doesn't make much sense because you would be creating a new `TextField` and never displaying it, not updating an existing `TextField`. Presumably you have a `TextField` called `ageDisplay` somewhere that you want to update.

Comment: Thank you Aaron! This has fixed the problem completely!