# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at AoW_2_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Tags: actionscript-3

Trying to do an assignment for school and I keep constantly getting this error and I don't know why at all and neither does my teacher. The first part of the code works fine but once its get to

```
fbe_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gofbe);
function gofbe(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("fbetext1");
}
```

It won't function properly and gives the error below in the output. As3 class is fbetext and instance name is fbe_mc and the label is fbetext1. I seem to be the only one having this issue in my class so help would be appreciated. Changed code accidentally had extra pieces that I forgot to delete

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at AoW_2_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

home_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoch1);
function gotoch1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("Chapter 1");
}

fbe_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gofbe);
function gofbe(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("fbetext1");
}
```

Comment: The **fbe_mc** object (whatever it is) must be present on timeline on the exact frame (different layer is fine) the code is at.

Comment: @Organis https://imgur.com/a/dN67ziC this is the stage screen, I took the fbe_mc (which is the image of the five basic elements, made in photoshop then imported as a jpeg onto the stage.) With 3 layers, code (as3), content (the images/text/buttons etc) and labels. But what I'm basically saying is I don't quite understand what you are saying.

edit - added an extra pic to the imgur to show full timeline

Comment: You seem to have more than one frame. Frames and listeners are a surefire way to lose control and get 1009s in unpredictable moments. `gotoAndStop()` **destroys** previous set of objects and creates a new one, therefore as soon as you click, the object you clicked gets destroyed. Also timeline coding is something added for compatibility at first, and you're not exactly in control of when that code gets executed. You can add `trace()` calls to each part of code and watch your log to find out what gets called, when and after what event. There's no direct cure to your problem, sadly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 -TypeError #1009 - any easy way to find out \*which\* object reference is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518118/as3-typeerror-1009-any-easy-way-to-find-out-which-object-reference-is-null)