# Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object ref AS3 project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, gif

I have AS3 project and Im trying to create a way to display GIF or SWF (converted online from the gif) in a similar way that I display a single image.

A single image is displayed with class and then referenced in Main.as. Similarly for gif or swf I extend MovieClip:

(yes I read other threads did not help)

```
package com.mee.mytest
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.events.Event;  
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Mee
     */

    public class MyTest extends MovieClip
    {
        [Embed(source="../../../../assets/spfx_MyClip.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private static const cMyTest : Class;
        private var swfMyClip : MovieClip;

        public function MyTest() 
        {
            swfMyClip = new cMyTest() as MovieClip;
            swfMyClip.scaleX = 600;
            swfMyClip.scaleY = 400;
            addChild(swfMyClip);

        }

    }

}
```

And now my main:

```
import com.mee.mytest.MyTest
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var vMyTest : MyTest; //this is var = the class

        public function Main() 
        {
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;          
            stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);           

            // touch or gesture? BLAH BLAH
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

            testMyGif();
        }

        function testmyGif():void
        {

            vMyTest = new MyTest();
            addChild(vMyTest);

        }
```

ERROR ERROR ERROR

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.mee.mytest::MyTest()
    at Main/testmyGif()
    at Main()
```

Comment: You don't embed other SWFs into your applications the way you did it. That means, **cMyTest** is not a valid **DisplayObject** class (I think embedding files like that produces a **ByteArray** class), which leads **new cMyTest() as MovieClip** to produce **null** reference rather than **MovieClip** instance. Hence, the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 -TypeError #1009 - any easy way to find out \*which\* object reference is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518118/as3-typeerror-1009-any-easy-way-to-find-out-which-object-reference-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

dem ... just for any1's sake. It mostly comes from 'Your displayed SWF is supposed to be in the same folder as the built swf, then the url has new URLRequest("myfile.swf") forget other folders or ..exiting folders, this is the only way to avoid any other URL errors

using

```
public var loader : Loader = new Loader();
public var urlRequ : URLRequest = new URLRequest("MyFile.swf")  

    loader.load(urlRequ);
    addChild(loader);
```